# Вывод необходимых индексов из списка

Tags: python, list, список

У меня есть список из чисел и мне нужно получить индексы тех чисел, которые подходят моему условию:

```
lst = [5,150,60,150,154,3,49]
for i in lst:
    if i > 100:
        large = (lst.index(i))
        print(large)
output
1
1
4
```

Итак, мне нужны были индексы чисел, которые больше 100. В моем списке два числа одинаковы (150) и вывод получился 1-1-4, а ожидаемый результат: 1-3-4 !

То есть, независимо от того, одинаковые ли числа, нужно получить актуальные индексы: каждое число, подходящее по условию - его реальный порядковый номер(индекс) в списке.

Надо или добавить еще условие, или вообще по другому записать код.

Answer (score 5):

Метод `index` возвращает индекс первого вхождения элемента в массив, поэтому такой вывод. Задачу можно решить с помощью функции `enumerate`:

```
lst = [5,150,60,150,154,3,49]
for index, i in enumerate(lst):
    if i > 100:
        print(index)
```

Функция `enumerate` генерирует кортежи, которые состоят из двух элементов: индекса массива и его значения. В данном случае, кортежи будут такие:

```
(0, 5)
(1, 150)
(2, 60)
(3, 150)
(4, 154)
(5, 3)
(6, 49)
```

Соответственно, проходя по кортежам можно сравнивать значение с требуемым порогом и выводить индекс, в случае, если условие выполняется.

Comment: Тогда уж просто ```print(*[i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j > 100])```

Answer (score 3):

Решение в духе вашего примера - для новичка:

```
lst = [5,150,60,150,154,3,49]
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if lst[i] > 100:
        print(i)
```

Так вызов функции `index`  вообще не нужен. Но предыдущий вариант с `enumerate` приятнее )