# Помогите решить задачу (поиск в листе и получение индекса)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано: строка разбивается на элементы в листе. Раньше строка не разбивалась и в ней было такое условие:

```
if ("http://") in text or ("https://") in text:
```

А там уже результатом занимался другой парсер, который выцеплял ссылку. Сейчас же строка разбивается на лист и каждый кусок находится в своём элементе. Нужно находить ссылки и получать их индексы, чтобы передать в другую функцию. Какие есть способы решения данной задачи? В голову пока приходит только постоянное выполнение цикла, который будет проходиться по элементам и искать в них нужный кусок текста, но я не уверен, что это правильный вариант, и возможно есть менее прожорливый способ (тот кусок кода выполняется всю программу).

Comment: Кроме как перебором вряд ли получится. Если бы не нужны были индексы элементов списка, можно было бы список конвертировать в set и работать с ним (так быстрее). Но, раз нужны индексы, то - цикл. А как получить индекс элемента списка сегодня уже писали [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/893805/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0)

Comment: Спасибо. Пока сделал так:
`for part in text:
                    if "http://" in part or "https://" in part:`
Что позволило без особых затрат сделать парсинг.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если конечной целью является получение всех ссылок в тексте, то можно с помощью re, но чтобы однозначно утверждать, желательно видеть вывод файла для парсинга. Таким образом (если это оформить в виде функции принимающей текст или список строк) на выходе можно получить список всех ссылок содержащихся в тексте.

```
import re
links = ['yandex', 'This is yandex https://yandex.ru/',
        'rambler', 'This is rambler http://rambler.ru/index.php']
s_links = ' '.join(links)

pat = re.compile('https?://\S+[\w/]')
print(re.findall(pat, s_links)) # ['https://yandex.ru/', 'http://rambler.ru/index.php']
```

Если-же нужен конкретно список индексов строк содержащих ссылки, то без цикла, боюсь, не удасться обойтись.

#### UPD

```
from re import findall
def links_grab(text):
    if type(text) == list:
        links = ' '.join(text)
    else:
        links = text
    return findall(r'https?://\S+[\w/]', links)


print(links_grab(in_text))
```